# File open - with open socket - ruby - reading file continuously

Tags: ruby, sockets, keep-alive, open-uri

```
require 'open-uri'
file_contents = open('local-file.txt') { |f| f.read }
```

taking the file open method forward.. how can we open and read a local file - with a  continuously live or changing data???

Some thing similar to live feed.. etc - other than reading the file say every 30 seconds.. is there a way to keep a file connection open  - so that we can log all changes happening...

Answer (score 1):

Read [`IO::open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-open) documentation :

> With no associated block, IO.open is a synonym for ::new. ***If the optional code block is given***, it will be passed io as an argument, and the IO object ***will automatically be closed when the block terminates***. In this instance, ::open returns the value of the block.

*without block*

```
file = File.open('doc.txt')
file.closed? # => false
```

*with block*

```
file = File.open('doc.txt') {|f| f }
file.closed? # => true
```

> is there a way to keep a file connection open - so that we can log all changes happening...

Then I can say don't use block with the `File::open` method.

Comment: yes connection is kept open.. can File::open be used to read live data changes.. ie check for live streaming data